# .babelrc ignore field seems to be ignored

Tags: babeljs

I've got a `.babelrc` file at the root of a project:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "ignore": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

When I compile it with `babel src --out-dir dist`, the `src` folder is still compiled onto the `dist` folder.

However, when I launch the command `babel src --out-dir dist --ignore src`, nothing is compiled.

Why is the `ignore` property of my `.babelrc` being ignored?

By the way, I've tried with some subfolder or files, and the same issue occurs.

Comment: assuming `.babelrc` and your `src` folder sit in the same parent folder, you perhaps need to supply `"ignore": ["src/**"]` or `"ignore": [/src/]` to it.

Comment: I've tried that, but have had no success

Comment: @YannBertrand, did you figured out how to make it work?

Comment: There's [an active bug](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726) reported for this issue btw in case you were pulling out your hair like I was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel ignore several directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748116/babel-ignore-several-directories)

Comment: The issue on GitHub is closed right now. You can verify and mark this question as answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3644) with babel-cli.

It has been fixed in v6.14.0. Here is the changelog for this version: https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v6.14.0

Comment: This has also been reported on babel 6.24.0 and 6.26.0: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3644