# Babel ignore several directories

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm currently running Babel with a simple command :

```
$ babel . --ignore node_modules --out-dir dist
```

But I can't find a way to ignore several directories (node_modules, test), I tried a lot of things, including (in `.babelrc`):

```
  "ignore": "node_modules"
  "ignore": "/node_modules/"
  "ignore": "node_modules/**"
  "ignore": ["node_modules"]
```

Which doesn't work at all (node_modules are transpiled). Isn't there a simple way to achieve this (with Babel 6)?

Comment: its a bug in babel itself.  https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726

Comment: you can do this , if you are using webpack

Comment: Well, I'm not using webpack here... And can't I specify several directories with the `--ignore` option via CLI? (Again, I tried a lot of stuff, but couldn't figure it out.)

Comment: Can you specify the directories you are trying to transpile instead? (workaround)

Comment: Yes I tried the only as well, again I have app.js and folders. Maybe the "only" options works in .babelrc. I'll try

Comment: I meant like `babel src folder1` instead of `babel .`

Comment: Ah yes indeed, well, the commas in the ignore are great! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be able to use commas in the cli

`babel . --ignore node_modules,test --out-dir dist`

Comment: Thanks, multiple `--ignore` didn't work...which is common in other tools. Instead the last `ignore` is used.

Answer (score 13):

You can ignore multiple directories and specify a globbing pattern within the `.babelrc` file like this

```
{
    ...,
    "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        "dir_2",
        "dir_3/**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Reference: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc

Answer (score 9):

With Babel 7 you need to use a glob pattern:

```
babel . --ignore */node_modules,*/test --out-dir dist
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that there's a known bug in babel, where it ignores `only` and `ignore` in `.babelrc`.

The relevant bug is [T6726](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3789), which has been [fixed in babel 6.14.0](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v6.14.0).

Comment: What did you mean? Can you give more details?