# Babel does not respect ignore API option

Tags: node.js, babeljs

Given the following minimal `package.json`:

```
{
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "ignore": [
      "b",
      "c",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "transpile": "babel *.js **/*.js --out-dir c"
  }
}
```

And a directory structure:

```
foo.js
a/
  bar.js
b/
  baz.js
```

`npm run transpile` steams through every directory, including the output directory if it exists:

```
foo.js -> c/foo.js
a/bar.js -> c/a/bar.js
b/baz.js -> c/b/baz.js
c/foo.js -> c/c/foo.js
```

What am I missing about the behaviour of the `ignore` option? `--ignore node_modules,b,c` on the command line works marginally better, although if an `--out-dir` is specified it seems only to respect the first argument.

Edit: per immediately above, the accepted answer to [Babel ignore several directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748116) does not solve the problem. Specifying an output directory seems somehow to cause all but the first directory specified to `--ignore` to be dropped from the list. In any case it doesn't explain why the `.babelrc` option seemingly has no effect... it's always tempting to cry 'bug', but I wondered if I'd missed something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel ignore several directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748116/babel-ignore-several-directories)

Comment: @stdob as above, commas in the command line option work, but only if not followed by an output directory.

Comment: Turns out it's likely a bug after all... https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726. Guess my search wasn't up to scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment above, there's a bug logged at https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6726. However it seems that the way to work around using the command line syntax is to avoid globs altogether. Instead of:

```
babel **/*.js --ignore b,c --out-dir c
```

I've had some success with:

```
babel . --ignore b,c --out-dir c
```