# Configure babel to compile a specific package inside node_modules when testing with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

By default, babel skips everything in `node_modules.` But I have one module under `/nodemodules/special-module` which is jsx, and needs compilation.

When building the main app, I solve this in `webpack.config.json` by including this in the `rules` array:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules(?!\/(special-module))/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}  // to transform JSX into JS
}
```

But webpack is not used when running tests with jest. I get an error showing that special-module is not being compiled.

```
.../myproject/node_modules/special-module/src/Special.jsx:151
                <div>
                ^    
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Instead, options have to be set in `.babelrc` where the equivalent should be

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "ignore": "node_modules\/(?!special-module)"
}
```

My understanding is that supplying an `ignore` key prevents the default exclusion of `node_modules`, ignoring only files matching the given regex. But the above does not seem to work. The `special-module` is still not compiled. This is using bable 6.23.0, so [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444716/babelrc-ignore-field-seems-to-be-ignored) should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Rather than putting the ignore in `.babelrc` it needs to go in the `transformIgnorePatterns` [jest setting](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string) in `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!special-module)"
    ]
    ...
  }
```

In fact I found I didn't need a `.babelrc` at all, as `babel-jest` is [automatically installed](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-babel).